# Intellij Maven dependency not resolved while following guide

Tags: java, maven, intellij-14

I am currently trying to follow [this guide](https://javacord.org/wiki/getting-started/setup/intellij-maven.html#setup) and every time I try to run the test code I am getting this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project MyBot: Could not resolve
> dependencies for project org.example:MyBot:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
> org.javacord:javacord:jar:3.4.0 was not found in
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This
> failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not
> reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or
> updates are forced -> [Help 1]

[pom.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q5nhz8v7LYo0bRNVyYEMzbeXmTqfGdND/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you post your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: It’s there: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/javacord/javacord/3.4.0/

Comment: I posted the pom file, i don't know if i did it correctly, im new here

Comment: Add code as text not as link.

Comment: How would i go about that, this is my 1st post

Comment: Edit your question and paste the code into it, with appropriate formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have to load the dependencies you added to the pom.xml.

in IntelliJ you can right click on your pom.xml chose maven -> reload Project.
This loads all dependencies from pom.xml.
Check the console output for any errors.

Comment: I have tried reloading the ide and the project, still not working

Answer (score 0):

Should the answer from Kaspatoo not working for you you can try to add the repository from Javacord to your project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you tell me how I would go about doing that

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, maven had downloaded the jars for the Dependency but wasn't loading them, I pointed maven to them in the system directory, and its working now